# How to implement a loop inside a websocket?

Tags: php, sockets, websocket, socket.io, ratchet

I have a php code that calls another php script to get new data for a cache "JSON string". Here is my current code what does the communication

```
if( ! isset($_COOKIE['ICWS_SESSION'])  ){
    throw new exception('Not Clocked In');
}

if( ! isset($_COOKIE['ICWS_STATION']) ){
    throw new exception('Missing Station Name');
}

$url = \classes\Cipher::decrypt($_COOKIE['ICWS_SESSION']);

$attrebutes = array('test');

//configure the connection
$conf = new ICWS\Config\Config($url, $_COOKIE['ICWS_STATION']); 

//create a new instance of icws
$icws = new ICWS\Connection($conf, $attrebutes); 

if ( !$icws->isLogged() ){
    throw new exception('Something Went Wrong when trying to login');
}

$messaging = new ICWS\Messaging($icws);

while(1){
$messaging->processMessages();
$myQueue = array();
$myQueue = array_merge( (array) $messaging->getCallsQueue(), (array) $messaging->getCurrentUserStatusQueue()) ;

echo json_encode($myQueue);
sleep(1);
}
```

Now, I want to add this code in a [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/) PHP WebSocket to ensure 1 TCP connection is made to the server per users to handle this request.

Here is my current websocket implementation.

```
<?php
namespace MyApp;
use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;

class Chat implements MessageComponentInterface {
    protected $clients;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
    }

    //open connection
    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        // Store the new connection to send messages to later
        $this->clients->attach($conn);

        echo "New connection! ({$conn->resourceId})\n";
    }

    //handle incoming messages from the client
    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {
        $numRecv = count($this->clients) - 1;
        echo sprintf('Connection %d sending message "%s" to %d other connection%s' . "\n"
            , $from->resourceId, $msg, $numRecv, $numRecv == 1 ? '' : 's');

        foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
            if ($from === $client) {
                // The sender is not the receiver, send to each client connected
                $client->send($msg);
            }
        }
    }

    //handle close connection
    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        // The connection is closed, remove it, as we can no longer send it messages
        $this->clients->detach($conn);

        echo "Connection {$conn->resourceId} has disconnected\n";
    }

    //handle errors
    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {
        echo "An error has occurred: {$e->getMessage()}\n";

        $conn->close();
    }
}
```

And here is how I start this WebSocket

```
<?php
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
use MyApp\Chat;

require dirname(__DIR__) . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
require dirname(__DIR__) . '/icws/MyApp/Chat.php';

$server = IoServer::factory(
    new HttpServer(
        new WsServer(
            new Chat()
        )
    ),
    8010
);

$server->run();
```

**Question**

Where in my implementation I would add my loop after the connection is made?

Here is what I have tried

```
<?php
namespace MyApp;
use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;

class icws implements MessageComponentInterface {
    protected $clients;
    protected $messaging;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
    }

    //open connection
    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        // Store the new connection to send messages to later
        $this->clients->attach($conn);

        echo "New connection! ({$conn->resourceId})\n";


        if( ! isset($_COOKIE['ICWS_SESSION'])  ){
            throw new exception('Not Clocked In');
        }

        if( ! isset($_COOKIE['ICWS_STATION']) ){
            throw new exception('Missing Station Name');
        }

        $url = \classes\Cipher::decrypt($_COOKIE['ICWS_SESSION']); 

        $attrebutes = array('test');

        //configure the connection
        $conf = new ICWS\Config\Config($url, $_COOKIE['ICWS_STATION']); 

        //create a new instance of icws
        $icws = new ICWS\Connection($conf, $attrebutes); 

        if ( !$icws->isLogged() ){
            throw new exception('Something Went Wrong when trying to login');
        }

        $this->messaging = new ICWS\Messaging($icws);


    }

    //handle incoming messages from the client
    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {
        $numRecv = count($this->clients) - 1;
        echo sprintf('Connection %d sending message "%s" to %d other connection%s' . "\n"
            , $from->resourceId, $msg, $numRecv, $numRecv == 1 ? '' : 's');

        foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
            if ($from === $client) {
                // The sender is not the receiver, send to each client connected
                $client->send($msg);
            }
        }
    }

    //handle close connection
    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        // The connection is closed, remove it, as we can no longer send it messages
        $this->clients->detach($conn);

        echo "Connection {$conn->resourceId} has disconnected\n";
    }

    //handle errors
    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {
        echo "An error has occurred: {$e->getMessage()}\n";

        $conn->close();
    }
}
```

Comment: `if ($from === $client) {` should be `if ($from !== $client) {`

Comment: What loop are you trying to add? Ratchet already implements an event loop. So you don't need to add another one. Use the events to react to an incoming message.